# How to generate random hashed password from form and send it to controller using ajax?

Tags: php, codeigniter, bcrypt

My login form is like this:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username" id="username">
<input type="password" name="password" id="password">
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Log In</button>
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#signin-form').submit(function() {
var email = $('#username').val(),
password = $('#password').val();
$.ajax({
url: '<?php echo site_url('account'); ?>',
type: 'post',
data: {username: username, password: password}
})
});
});
</script>
```

What I want is I want to send the password in hashed form not in plain text using bcrypt. So hhow to do this?

Comment: https://github.com/dwightwatson/codeigniter-bcrypt#checking, it says here to pass the `raw string password` and the `hashed string password` to verify

Comment: Thanks buddy for the help, but I don't want to send the plain password from the form. I just want to send hashed password from the form as I'm using ajax and if I send password in plain form, then my password gets easily hacked. The code you suggested only works if I send the plain password, but if I send the hashed password, then it returns false. Is there any solution for this problem or sending the plain password is only the option?

Comment: your question is different from what you wanted, put it a little more code and details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far i understand you want to send hash password and retrieve it?

this code works only on php 5.5 or higher

```
 echo password_hash(variable, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

The first parameter is the password string that needs to be hashed and the second parameter specifies the algorithm that should be used for generating the hash.

The default algorithm is currently bcrypt, but a stronger algorithm may be added as the default later at some point in the future and may generate a larger string. If you are using `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` in your projects, be sure to store the hash in a column that’s capacity is beyond 60 characters. Setting the column size to `255` might be a good choice. You could also use `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` as the second parameter. In this case the result will always be `60` characters long.

In your case, to use password_hash, create a ajax code that will pass your password value to and use the code above, and after that. To verify your password use this code

```
<?php
if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
// Success!
// the first parameter is your password that's not yet encrypted, the secode is your password encrypted
}
else {
// Invalid password
}
```

this is ajax code

```
<script>
   function createHash()
   {
      var xmlhttp;
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
           xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
      else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
           xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
           if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
           {
               document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }

       }
     xmlhttp.open("GET","file.php?pass="+password,true);
     xmlhttp.send();
   }
 </script>
```

and in your `file.php`

```
$GLOBAL['hash']=password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$pass = $_GET['pass'];
echo $GLOBALS['hash'];
```

don't forget to create a div container and name it myDiv, the hash password will show there and to get the value do the code below

```
var new_pass= document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML;
```

and also don't forget to call the `function createHash()`

and i almost forgot. this is the code to verify the password

```
<?php
    if (password_verify($oldpass, $GLOBAL['hash'])) {
     // Success!
     // the first parameter is your password that's not yet encrypted, the secode is your password encrypted
    }
    else {
     // Invalid password
    }
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Actually I'm not using the default one, I am using the [bcrypt library](https://github.com/dwightwatson/codeigniter-bcrypt). I tried to send the code like this in ajax: `var hash = <?php echo $this->bcrypt->hash_password('#password'); ?> $.ajax({ url: '<?php echo site_url('account'); ?>', type: 'post', data: {email: email, pass: hash} })` But it's not working. Can you just suggest me the correct idea about how to send the hashed password to the controller via ajax?

Comment: i finish editing my answer, the rest is up to you. hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was pretty helpful.

Comment: up this answer if this is useful

Comment: I have a problem in bcrypt. To verify a password, I need a password that is not hashed. But according to my code, hashed password is sent to the controller through ajax not the one that is not hashed because if I sent the password that is not hashed, then it could be seen in firebug. My db password is also in bcrypt form. So how can I verify password as the first parameter must be the password that has not been hashed?

Comment: to verify the password use this code ` if (password_verify($oldpass, $GLOBAL['hash'])) {`

Comment: hey, i have a question, how can i edit the script code using firebug?

Comment: In the console tab, there is command history button at the bottom. There you can write js codes.

Comment: i saw that, and i can edit html code but not the script

Comment: Check these links [Firebug DOM](http://getfirebug.com/dom) and [Firebug JavaScript](http://getfirebug.com/javascript).